# How do i 'professionally' store small data in python?

Tags: python

I want to become a software developer. When I'm building apps for my portfolio, I'm usually storing small amounts of data in text files like these:

Script for a visual novel game:

```
# used .split(' ++ ')
# Image ++ Person ++ Quote
img1 ++ Monika ++ Today looks like a rainy day!
img2 ++ Jack ++ No, today looks like a sunny day!
img1 ++ Monika ++ No, today will be a HORRIBLE day!
```

Subreddit's log:

```
#submission's name \n link


Bug Report: Selecting Jaina loads you in as Valeera.
https://www.reddit.com/r/heroesofthestorm/comments/fms1k9/bug_report_selecting_jaina_loads_you_in_as_valeera/

All missing potential Heathstone Portraits
https://www.reddit.com/r/heroesofthestorm/comments/fnbcvw/all_missing_potential_heathstone_portraits/
```

Is there a more 'professional' way of doing this? I don't want to bring excel or sql for tiny stuff.

Should I just use a database?

If I want to do it *my* way, how do I separate entries to ensure that users can't accidentally break it?

If i have a **SINGLE** variable that needs to be stored permanently, is it fine to just use a .txt file?

Comment: There are tons of storage formats. Python directly ships with ``pickle``, ``json``, ``csv``, ..., and there are many third-party libraries for various storage means. There is really no single "the way" unless you provide more detail on what you need.

Comment: Check out `sqlite3`.Small database, used in mobile applications as well

Comment: @BruceWayne No, not all of my questions.

Comment: @MBee - StackOverflow is primarily a "one question at a time" site.  If you have multiple questions/problems, then that would be multiple questions (of course, with your attempts).